# Detecting url scheme in settings.py of Django app

Tags: django

My Django web app allows users to connect via both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. I'm curious: is there a way to detect the url scheme in **settings.py**? If so, how?

Comment: You can't do it in *settings.py* file because it just contains constants and variables. It doesn't process requests. So, no way to detect URL scheme. But this can be done in a middleware.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. I'm loading some static files from a 3rd party storage bucket (Azure). I want these objects' uris to have `http` for http requesting users, and to be `https` for https requesting users. So should I just use a middleware to pass the correct scheme to my `Storage` class?

Comment: Yes, if it can be done using a middleware, then do it. All you need to do is check for `request.is_secure()`. It's `True` for HTTPS requests. Although, this can be done in view, too.

Comment: Sounds good. Just add all that as a reply, and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Posted all that in an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done in *settings.py* file as it contains only constants and variables. It doesn't process requests. But this can be done in a middleware.

Here's a middleware in it's simplest form to check URL scheme:

```
class DetectUrlScheme(object):
    """ Middleware for detecting URL scheme """

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.is_secure():
            # HTTPS
            # do something ...
        else:
            # HTTP
            # do something ...
        return
```

Although, if you've got only a couple of views, writing a middleware seems an overhead. So, you can check URL scheme in your views, too.

```
def myview(request):
    if request.is_secure():
        # HTTPS
        # do something ...
    else:
        # HTTP
        # do something ...
```